# How to set shadow for custom view of UITableViewCell in swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, layer, shadow

I have tried this but didn't work for me:

```
cell.totalView?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
cell.totalView?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
cell.totalView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
cell.totalView?.layer.shadowRadius = 10
cell.totalView?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Comment: why not using a view in it and give it shadow

Answer (score 1):

Try adding shadow for your custom view from `awakeFromNib` method of custom cell.

E.g.

Add following method in your customTableViewCell class

```
func dropShadow(view: UIView, shadowOpacity: Float = 0.2, shadowColor: CGColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor, shadowRadius: CGFloat = 5){
    view.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    view.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
}
```

And call it from `awakeFromNib` method like

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    dropShadow(view: yourCustomView, shadowOpacity: 0.2, shadowColor: UIColor.yellow.cgColor, shadowRadius: 5)        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make insideView in CustomViewCell and load this function in awakeFromNib()

```
func ui() {

    insideView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    insideView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    insideView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    insideView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    insideView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set masksToBounds as true

```
  cell.totalView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one UIVIew in table cell with margin of 8 from all sides.

Create one file with name `CardView.swift`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CardView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 1
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.black
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.1

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }
}
```

[image]
Just add custom class in storyboard